# ImportError: cannot import name 'Request' from 'request'

Tags: python, importerror

When i install "http module" using this command "pip3 install http" an error was occurred

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\ibrah\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ibrah\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dn_zr423\\http\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ibrah\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dn_zr423\\http\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-4bhyjyb0'
     cwd: C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dn_zr423\http\
Complete output (7 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dn_zr423\http\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    import http
  File "C:\Users\ibrah\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dn_zr423\http\http\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from request import Request
ImportError: cannot import name 'Request' from 'request' (c:\users\ibrah\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\request\__init__.py)
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

How to solve this

Comment: Can you please mention which `pip` version are you using to install the module?

Comment: It is the latest version. I think 20.0

Comment: Is it the full traceback? Can you provide the full installation log? Also, when you install put a `-v` flag. Like `pip3 install -v http`